# How to add values of type unsigned integer into array in the function's argument?

Tags: c, arrays, integer

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? I tried to compile it and received "Abort (core dumped)". I'm not sure how to insert the values into the array passed as an argument of the function. Word is `typedef` of `unsigned int`.

Here's my code:

```
int relocate(const Word program[], unsigned int instr_num,
    unsigned int data_num, int offset, Word relocated_program[],
    unsigned short * const instrs_changed)
{
    Word word, op, mem, new_mem, result;
    int i, n = 0;

    if (program != NULL && instr_num != 0 && instr_num + data_num <= 3072 && offset % 4 == 0 && instrs_changed != NULL)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < instr_num + data_num; i++)
        {
            word = program[i];
            op = word >> 28;
            if (op != 8 && op != 12 && op != 13)
            {
                relocated_program[i] = word;
            } 
            else
            {
                mem = (word << 4) >> 13;
                new_mem = (mem + offset) << 9;
                result = (word & new_mem);
                relocated_program[i] = result;
                n++; * instrs_changed = n;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to add how you are calling you function in your question (ie which arguments are you passing).

Comment: You are not attempting to make an array which was given as a parameter to be bigger after returning from the funciton, are you?

Comment: To make Prateeks comment clearer, with any question about unexpected behaviour of a program, you need to provide a [mre]. It nees to be both minimal and reproducable. The shown code is not reproducable and I doubt it is minimal.